# Getting the content from the database in the template without loops?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am having model called furniture and I am having template and also wrote my views and I want to the single phrase from the database 
My views.py

```
def project3(request):
    furn=furniture.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'project3.html',{'furniture':furn});
```

My template is:

```
<div class="col-4">

              <h6 class="display-6 mt-3"><b><center>{{furniture.phrase}}</center></b></h6>
              <p class="demo"><center>I'm designing the room </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6 mt-3">{{furniture.phrase}}</b></h6>
              <p class="demo">I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6 mt-3"><b>{{furniture.phrase}}</b></h6>
              <p class="demo">I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </p>
```

My models.py:

```
class furniture(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phrase=models.CharField(max_length=60,default='111111')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phrase
```

There are three phrases in the database but i am rendering them and I am not getting them in the webpage please help me out from this?

Comment: for accessing each object in queryset you should index furniture query in your template it will be `furniture.0.phrase` and `furniture.1.phrase` and so on

Comment: @ mahyar you mean in template

Comment: yes in template but it is not good practice to do so

Comment: no @mahyar i am not getting